# How does a jetpack-compose composable become aware of its children?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[This android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-basics#5) has the below code snippet:

```
@Composable
private fun MyApp() {
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

My first thought was that the Surface composable gets its Greeting child by calling the lambda parameter containing the child and getting it back as a return value.  But later in the tutorial we get this example:

```
@Composable
private fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Hello,")
            Text(text = name)
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow the Column is aware of both the "Hello" Text and the name Text, even though calling the lambda would only give the name Text as a return value.

So my question is:  what is the mechanism that makes a Composable aware of its children?

Comment: Note that the same can be said about really any Compose example. If you have a composable function with single `Text()` inside it then you also do not pass/return the result of `Text()` anywhere. Calling `Text()` adds it to the layout automatically. The same happens with `Greeting()` - it is not returned, it is added to column simply by calling `Greeting()`. I'm not sure how does it work internally though - maybe the compiler plugin rearranges the code or maybe Compose keeps the current context globally or thread-local.

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I managed to miss that!  I've rephrased the question to use simpler examples and more directly address the knowledge I'm lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to for example `suspend` functions, `@Composable` functions are processed by the compiler in a very special way. This is to allow automatic recompositions and also to implicitly pass the context between components.

Documentation for [@Composable](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.runtime/runtime/1.0.5-source/androidx/compose/runtime/Composable.kt.html) specifies:

> A useful mental model for Composable functions is that an implicit "composable context" is passed into a Composable function, and is done so implicitly when it is called from within another Composable function. This "context" can be used to store information from previous executions of the function that happened at the same logical point of the tree.

We can see it in action by writing a simple composable function and analyzing the resulting bytecode. Taking this source code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Foo() {
    Text("foo")
}
```

We get the bytecode consisting of hundreds of instructions and some of the resulting code is even placed in a separate, synthesized class. We will focus on most important parts:

```
public static final void Foo(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int);
```

As we can see, our parameterless `Foo()` function actually implicitly receives a `Composer` and some integer.

```
3: invokeinterface #24,  2           // InterfaceMethod androidx/compose/runtime/Composer.startRestartGroup:(I)Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;
```

Another `Composer` object is acquired by calling `startRestartGroup()` on the received `Composer`.

```
55: invokestatic  #73                 // Method androidx/compose/material/TextKt."Text-fLXpl1I":(Ljava/lang/String;Landroidx/compose/ui/Modifier;JJLandroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontStyle;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontWeight;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/font/FontFamily;JLandroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextDecoration;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/style/TextAlign;JIZILkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Landroidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;III)V
```

This is a call to `Text()`. It is hard to read due to the large number of optional parameters, but we can notice that it also receives a `Composer` object. This parameter is synthesized, we can't find it in the list of `Text()` parameters - similarly as in our `Foo()` function.

`Foo()` passes the composer acquired with `startRestartGroup()` to `Text()`.

While I don't know the exact functionality and the meaning of the `Composer`, we can clearly see that Compose framework implicitly passes the context between composable functions, making possible to wire components together.

Comment: Thanks again!  While this satisfies my curiosity, if anyone wants a more technical explanation of how Compose works internally, I also found this article somewhat helpful:  https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/under-the-hood-of-jetpack-compose-part-2-of-2-37b2c20c6cdd

Comment: BTW, a composer is not created when `startRestartGroup` is called. We always return the composer. We did this to be able to change the composer in the future as an optimization. We currently don't do this optimization but if and when we do the existing libraries will continue to work correctly.

Comment: A explanation of what the composer is and how it works can be found here: http://intelligiblebabble.com/compose-from-first-principles/  This is a bit dated as it was created before compose 1.0 but give the principles it discusses are still true, the details are a bit off.

Comment: @chuckj Oh, thank you very much for additional information! I definitely should read the source code of Jetpack Compose (or Jetbrains Compose implementation) one day, because this stuff seems super interesting. I also changed "create" to "acquire" in my answer to be more accurate.